# Why is this variable in quotes not working?

Tags: javascript

I have this countdown plugin I'm using. I'm trying to make the ate that the countdown gets is dynamic. But I'm running into a few problems.

First of all, this is the code:

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
  var date = <?php echo $book_date; ?>;
  $(".description").countdown(date, function(event) {
    $(this).text(
      event.strftime('%D days %H:%M:%S')
    );
  });
</script>
```

This `<script>` is being used in a PHP while loop. When I look at the source code, the code is properly outputting and the `date` JS variable is correctly changing every time the while loop is repeated.

Now I just want to output the `date` variable into the countdown plugin. When I do this:

```
$(".description").countdown("4/5/2017", function(event) {
```

The code works fine. How do I replace the text version of this date with the variable version that contains the same text?

Comment: Add quotes around your PHP variable output - `var date = '<?php echo $book_date; ?>';`

Comment: @Rob You deserve the accepted answer :)

Comment: The question seems vague to me. From what i understood, you're having the answer already to your question. Do you want multiple date instances?

Comment: Seems like @user6902601 had a syntax error. :)